# Knitting to Word file (in a loop)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to create Word files within a loop (one Word file for each school).
Knitr seems not to have a `knit2word` function (but `knit2html`, `knit2pdf` etc.). Can this still be done?

```r
schools <- c("A", "B", "C")

for(school in schools){
  knitr::knit("analysis.Rmd", output=paste0("stats_school ", school, ".R"))
}
```

The Rmd file starts like this:

```
---
title: "The title"
author: "My Name"
output: word_document
---
```

Comment: Since you want to create word documents, I think you are looking for [`render()`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/render.html) function from `{rmarkdown}`  package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render your Rmd in a loop (whether to word or html or ... ) you could use `rmarkdown::render`:

```
schools <- c("A", "B", "C")

for(school in schools){
  rmarkdown::render("analysis.Rmd", output_file=paste0("stats_school ", school))
}
```